# WinSparkle silent automatic update

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I' trying to use `WinSparkle` library in aplication created using Visual c++ for automatic updates.

I found that they have "silent update" functionality. And I suppose it should not show form that tells

"`A new version of ... is available`" with buttons "`Skip this version`", `"Remaind me later"` and `"Install update"`.

There is argument `sparkle:installerArguments` with possible value SILENT. But how to use it? I suppose I need to put it to xml file that on server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle">
<channel>
    <title>Example app updates</title>
    <link>http://winsparkle.org/example/appcast.xml</link>
    <description>Appcast for Example app updates.</description>
    <language>en</language>
    <item>
      <title>Version 1.5.4</title>
      <sparkle:releaseNotesLink>http://winsparkle.org/example/relnotes.html</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
      <sparkle:installerArguments>SILENT</sparkle:installerArguments>
      <pubDate>Tue, 15 Sep 2012 18:11:12 +0200</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/poedit/poedit/1.5/poedit-1.5.4-setup.exe"
                 sparkle:version="1.5.4"
                 type="application/octet-stream"/>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

This didn't helped - I still have form that informs regarding new version.

How to make "silent" update?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that the UI dialog you are referring to cannot be suppressed. The "/SILENT" option is passed to the enclosure when it runs, so that the setup program that contains the update can run silently ("/SILENT" is a feature of InnoSetup).

But WinSparkle does not support updates without user confirmation. This is the behavior *most* software should use. Of course, there are scenarios, such as a large corporate environment or unattended servers, that we want updates to be automatic and not require user interaction. WinSparkle is not useful for that (unless you modify the code and compile yourself)

Answer (score 0):

Reed documentation https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle/wiki/Appcast-Feeds

You should add here to the enclosure
this `sparkle:installerArguments="/SILENT /SP-"`

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?  Version 0.4 was released on September 6th 2014, but installerArguments was merged only on [April 25th 2015](https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle/pull/57#issuecomment-96179784).  You'll probably have to [build it yourself](https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle#-building-from-sources).